# How to count the number of entries a user has selected in a multivalue field of a tool dialogue using Python and ArcGIS 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, excel

I am currently creating a script that will read data in one (to many) Excel spreadsheet(s) and would like to know how to get a count of the number of spreadsheets entered by the user. The script will only read the data in the GISData$ sheet of each spreadsheet file. So far I have the below code but need something to replace 'rowCount' as this doesn't seem to be working. I would like to just get a count of the number of spreadsheets selected.

```
spreadsheets = arcpy.GetParameter(1)

for idx in range(0, spreadsheets.rowCount):
    input_spreadsheet = str(spreadsheets.getValue(idx,0))
        input_spreadsheet += r"\GISData$

...do something...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question will help you working with Excel files & sheets: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65035/how-to-read-an-excel-sheet-in-arcpy-script Then if you have a multivalue parameter, you can treat it as a list and return its length (if there's only 1 GISData] sheet per xls file)

Comment: What datatype is the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that  `arcpy.GetParameter(1).values` is a list.
So you can try `len(arcpy.GetParameter(1).values)` to get a count of the number of values selected.

Comment: This returns 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: if arcpy.GetParameter(1) is already a list the count is the size of this list  : `len(arcpy.GetParameter(1))`