# Can arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer() cope with *xls files in script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, import, excel, error-000732

I am trying to create a point FeatureClass from an Excel-File using a standalone python-script. I am applying the method "arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer()" which works fine using *.xlsx files. However, I am having problems using *xls files. It also works for *.xls files using the python-window in ArcGIS directly, but not in my standalone script.

For my script I get this error:

> ERROR 000732: XY Table: Dataset C:...\data_for_GIS.xls\sheet1$ does
>   not exist or is not supported

Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteoutput = True

folder = r"C:/..."
excelfile = "Test.xls"
coordsystem = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"

arcpy.env.workspace = folder

table = "sheet1"
intable = folder + os.sep + excelfile + os.sep + table + "$"


arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(intable,"GEOLON","GEOLAT","LAYER",coordsystem)
```

Comment: I updatet my question with my code. As I sayed it works for *.xlsx files but not for *.xls files. However, it works for both in the python window

Comment: Try naming your objects without special characters like the trailing dollar sign.

Comment: @Vince the trailing dollar sign is actually necessary for loading excelfiles into ArcGIS

Comment: I would first convert the Excel sheet to a table, using the Excel Toolset, Excel to Table.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65037/59

Comment: Are you trying to run from 64bit Background geoprocessing?  I've found that trying to open XLS files from 64bit arcpy usually gives that message.  Try running from 32bit python.

Comment: @Midavalo I guess I am using 64bit backgroud geoprocessing. How can I change to 32bit w/o deinstalling 64bit? Is there a possibility to use 32bit just for reading in the excelfile and change to 64bit after that line in the scipt. As it is quite a long scipt I would prefer to use 64bit.

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall How does that answer my question? What is to see there?

Comment: Oops, wrong link, I meant to suggest that you try the Excel to table tool mentioned in this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/68764/59

Comment: @Alex how are you running your python?  From the command line, or via other software?  If from the command line you may just need to switch to the 32bit python folder for your python.exe (I have both installed, one in c:\python27\arcgis10.3\ and the other in c:\python27\arcgisx64\10.3)

Comment: @Midavalo I have installed both aswell, but how do I actually change it? I will use the script as an ArcGIS-script-tool, but for the command line it would be nice to know, aswell.

Comment: As it stands the error presented is not a copy/paste from running your code snippet.  I think you should trim your snippet down some more, then run it against a simple test data set, and then show us the precise output when run in an IDE like IDLE. You are importing `xlrd` and `xlwt` but not using them in the code snippet.

Comment: @PolyGeo Well, I just copied the error and then I changed the path, b/c I don't think anybody must know or needs to know. The code works fine using *.xlsx but not using *.xls. I am not really sure what you would like me to change in my question.

Comment: Try copying your spreadsheets to a file location like C:\temp while you are testing so that you don't have to do anything other than copy/paste the code snippet you run and the error that you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as we got now, I would say that it is a bug. I am still confused a bit as it works in the python window with *.xls files and *.xlsx files, but not using a stand alone script. I solved the problem now, as I import the data from the *.xls file to python using xlrd and export it to a *.xlsx file using xlsxwriter. Maybe not the smartest work around, but it works.